# How to avoid host header injection/poisoning in apache tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, server

Want to stop host header injection or poisoning in Apache tomcat server. Is it possible by creating virtual host .

Answer (score 1):

It's best to not trust the Host header if you can help it. A virtual host is one way to fix part of the issue.

Have you tried any of the following (virtual host is included)?

1. Rejecting any request that doesn't match the target domain via CORS or something similar.
2. Validating Host header to ensure that the request is originating from that
   target host or not.
3. In Apache/Nginx, as a reverse proxy to your tomcat server, create a dummy virtual host that catches all requests with unrecognized Host headers.
4. Creating a whitelist of trusted domains during the initial setup of the application and mapping domains received in Host header of each and every request with it.
5. Disable the support for the `X-Forwarded-Host` header and if can’t be disabled put proper security checks on it to prevent its tampering.

Comment: Thanks!  I will look to create the virtual host here.